# Read line from file and load it to actual config

Tags: scala, config, typesafe-config

I'm using the [ConfigFactory](https://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html) class to load the config of my application, but i want to know how can I load a line from other file and add it to the Config object.
The file only contains 1 line with the value I want, and i want to add that value with to the config with a new key or better to a existing one, so i can have a default value.

Is it possible to add a custom key/value after the config is loaded?, like:

`config.add("key", "value")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `#withFallback`:

```scala
// Assuming this is your first config file
val default = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")

// Now we add the second one
val updated = default.withFallback(ConfigFactory.load("foo.conf"))
```

---

Or, assuming you have read your `line` elsewhere as a value, use the same method but parse the config from the string directly using `ConfigFactory#parseString`:

```scala
val default = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
val updated = default.withFallback(ConfigFactory.parseString(s"key = $value"))
```

Comment: But i don't want load another config file, i just want to add the string inside the file to a value on the actual config. With your method, it loads a config file, isn't it?
In my file there is not any config structure, just a value.
In case that i can do that with a simple value inside the file, how can i access to that value then?

Comment: How can i access to the value from the parseString(line)? 
I think i didn't explain well. 
In the file there is only a value, there aren't any key-value just a value. Ej: `1234` and i want to add a atribute to the config like `"password": 1234`